# Is it possible to catch a warning and choose to continue from where the warning left off?

Tags: python, request, python-requests

Is there a way to use either a warning or exception in python that would allow me to raise control and then pick up from where it left off?

```
def foo():
    #make a request
    r = request.get('someRestAPI')
    # get the data from request
    data = r.json()
    # determine the number of results the request will return
    num_results = data['num_results']
    if num_results > 1000:
         # raise a warning to be handled main
         # continue if the main doesn't catch
    results = []
    endpoint = data['next_page']
    while endpoint:
         # request the next page
         r = request.get(endpoint )
         data = r.json()
         results.append(data['result'])
         endpoint = data['next_page']

 def main():
     try:
         foo()
     catch warning:
         cont = input("Warning Over 1000 results, Continue?")
         if cont == 'y':
              # return to function call and continue
```

The goal of the example above is to show a possible use case. I make an initial request to a REST API and determine the number of results that request will give. If I have too many results, then I want to temporary pass control to another area of the program to determine if we should continue.

I know that this program could be structured differently to accomplish this, but I'm curious if there's a way to specifically give control via a raise or warning to the function that called it and then allow it to continue from where it left off.

Comment: An exception exits the function completely, there is no way to resume it based on whether its caught higher on the call stack. If it is not caught it will eventually cause the program to terminate. Some curiosities are best left unexplored, simply because they will never lead to anything useful. `raise control and then pick up from where it left off` sounds pretty much like what a function does.

Comment: So, it would take a good bit of work.  if you throw, you can dump variables to a file; then everytime you you run your app check for a file and load those variables.  The issue is then the whole "resume", which would require a better design and maybe rerun particular functions.  What is the root reason why you want to do this?  Maybe there is a better solution to your problem than throwing exceptions etc.

Comment: IMO, it doesn't seem _pythonic_ to be using exceptions in this situation. this seems like a control-flow problem to me. it is probably better treated with coroutines and yielding control & messages between `main` & `foo`

Comment: given the sample OP put up, there is most definitely a better solution.  Exceptions/Errors etc are for actual errors and neither fit that use case.

Comment: I can see what you mean by this process not being pythonic. Let's say my code is being used by multiple other programs and has some unusual, tricky, and long authentication process (not my own). My thoughts were, I wonder if there is a way to give a calling program a chance at cancelling the process if it will take too long to complete. My user might give a search query that returns more results than excepted and I looking for a better way to prompt them to continue.

Comment: The short answer is: no. There are two different basic designs for exception handling, termination-model and resumptive-model. Python, like almost all other modern languages with exceptions, uses the termination model, and, as you can guess from the names, that means you can't resume from an exception.

Comment: You should be able to find a lot more information (theory, history, implementation details, how to work around each one with the other, etc.) from searching on those terms; if you want an answer specifically on one of those aspects, it might be a good question (or it might not—e.g., I don't know if anyone knows why Guido chose the termination model, even decades-later Guido, beyond that he probably read the same papers as Stroustrop and everyone else…).

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a better solution to your problem and that you shouldnt need exceptions etc as real errors/exceptions arent occurring.

First:  Create more modularity. I personally prefer to make a lot of functions that make sense.  Ill do a quick conversion for ya.

```
def main():
  data = get_data()
  if data['num_results'] > 1000:
    cont = input("Warning Over 1000 results, Continue?")
    if cont == 'y':
      results = process_data(data)
  if results is not None:
    #do things.

def get_data():
  r = request.get('someRestAPI')
  return r.json()

def process_data(data):
  results = []
  endpoint = data['next_page']
  while endpoint:
    # request the next page
    r = request.get(endpoint )
    data = r.json()
    results.append(data['result'])
    endpoint = data['next_page']
  return results

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Now this doesnt answer the question, but reorganizes your code as to allow it to be more smooth and no exceptions are needed.